# Trigger compile time error when given overload of the constexpr function is called

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, constexpr

I am writing custom variadic template that performs lookup in compile-time map.

The problem is, I want to trigger compile-time error each time the value is not found in that map - preferably with descriptive error message.

example code:

```
template<key_t k, class pair, class... pairs>
static constexpr value_t get_local(std::tuple<pair, pairs...>)
{
    return (pair::key == k) ? pair::value : get_local<k>(std::tuple<pairs...>{});
}

template<key_t k> static constexpr value_t get_local(std::tuple<>)
{
    // Trigger error!
}
```

I can leave `get_local` undefined in the second part of code, and it actually triggers linker error, but that is not falling into category of "descriptive error message".

Static asserts, I believe, would be of no use here.

I am using C++ 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And immediate drop in solution is to `delete` the overload:

```
template<key_t k> static constexpr value_t get_local(std::tuple<>) = delete;
```

This will provide the *somewhat* descriptive message that we try to use a base case that doesn't exist.

Alternatively, with a static assertions in place:

```
template<key_t k> struct always_false { static constexpr bool value = false; };

template<key_t k> static constexpr value_t get_local(std::tuple<>)
{
    static_assert(always_false<k>::value, "Hit bad case!");
    return std::declval<value_t>();
}
```

The `always_false` utility is needed to make the assertion condition dependent, so the template is not ill-formed; no diagnostic required, as `static_assert(false, ...)` would make it.

Mind you, that you instantiate this overload yourself in your own conditional operator:

```
(pair::key == k) ? pair::value : get_local<k>(std::tuple<pairs...>{});
```

When you hit the case of a tuple with a single element. Both "branches" of the conditional expression must be valid. Best handle it conditionally with an `if constepxr`:

```
if constexpr (pair::key == k) return pair::value;
else                          return get_local<k>(std::tuple<pairs...>{});
```

Since you did indicate `pair::key == k` can be evaluated in a constant expression.

Comment: Argh, 1 minute late. How about `static_assert(sizeof...(pairs) > 0, "Descriptive error");` ? The assertion gets descriptive itself

Comment: static_assert trick does not work with Clang - it printed `Hit bad case!` even if the function was not called

Comment: @PiotrK - Sorry, but no [mcve], means I can't help. It works for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2034b4c031bbe1a9 - And conforms to how I understand the language.

Comment: @StoryTeller Catch! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f9df200bbdab9a

Comment: @PiotrK - Well, that clears it up. `static_assert` is not fired when a function is *called*. It's fired when the template is *instantiated*. Which you do in `: get_local<k>(std::tuple<pairs...>{});`. I'll amend the answer.